# How to find the limit of a given Multi-Variable Function $z = f(x,y)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Find $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,1)}\arctan\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+(y-1)^2}\right).$$

I tried both plugging in which gives $\arctan\left(\frac{-1}{0}\right)$, which doesn't work.

I tried subbing $y=mx$, which gave me an answer I couldn't simplify.

Is there another way of going about doing this problem, or proving that the limit DNE (does not exist), which I suspect?

Comment: $\arctan{\frac{-1}{0}}=\arctan{(-\infty)}=-\frac{\pi}{2}$. And, you should learn to type math.

Comment: Also, why would $y=mx$ work? These lines don't always intersect the point $(0,1)$. To go this route, one would try $y-1 = mx$, but generally this doesn't prove a limit exists, only to disprove its existence.